# Timing limiter for execution of commands in Bash/Shell Script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a shell script which looks like this:

```
echo firstOutput
read -s
command0
command1a
command1b
command1c
echo secondOutput
command2
```

`command1a`, `command1b`, `command1c` are individual commands but they can be executed in arbitrary order and are a group in the sense of the following explanation.

I now want to improve it so the script continues even if one command gets stuck. `command0` needs to be executed first and it got 8 seconds to operate. If it doesn't make it within 8 seconds, the script shall continue to `command1[a-c]` which together have 5 seconds to operate. If they don't terminate within the given 5 seconds, `command2` shall be called. Just in case this matters: `command2` is the last command of this script.

Edit: To clarify: I know how to make a script which executes the commands in the maximum time allowed. However, these are timeouts and I want the script to run through as fast as possible. The entire script usually runs through in a fraction of a second after enter is pressed (see line `read -s`).

Answer (score 3):

```
echo firstOutput
read -s

command0 &
sleep 8

command1a &
command1b &
command1c &
sleep 5

echo secondOutput
command2
```

Comment: Exactly what I would have done...  Upvoted!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `timeout` command does exactly what you seem to want. See `man timeout`:

```
NAME
   timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
   timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
   timeout [OPTION]

DESCRIPTION
   Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
```

Comment: The problem being that `timeout` will kill the command, which doesn't look like what the OP intents. OP just wants the next set of commands to start once the timeout expires.

Comment: @muru That's right. I want the previous commands to continue running when the other commands are called. I don't want any of them to be forcefully terminated.